# R equivalent of a sub routine

Tags: r, fortran

Is there an eqivalent of a fortran subroutine in R?.  I have a script that I wish to run parsing a number of different variables (file names, plot limits and so on). At the moment I make a copy and reset these in each new copy which is a bit tedious.  It would be nicer to call the script somehow and parse the variables each time like I can do in Fortran.

Comment: You should maybe go beyond executing simple expressions from the command line and create your own **function** to systematize repetitive work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions:

```
myProd <- function(x,y) {
    return(x*y)
}

z <- myProd(3,5)
z
[1] 15
```